# Twitter Bootstrap carousel doesn't work on older browsers

Tags: jquery-plugins, cross-browser, carousel, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

[Per the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel), this should be enough to run Twitter Bootstrap:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.carousel').carousel()
```

I also included `jquery.transitions` plugin so I assumed it would degrade in older browsers.
Unfortunately, the slides don't move at all in Firefox 3.6. Why?

Comment: I am trying to make this work too. Could you please edit the question with your <!-- items included so I can see if I mess it up there?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Took me a while to set up, this helped me: http://getkirby.com/blog/bootstrap-carousel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you need to add `slide` class to your carousel for the `simple` version to work:

```
<div class="carousel slide">
```

Sample carousel has it, and there is a check in the code:

```
if (!$.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
  this.$element.trigger('slide')
  $active.removeClass('active')
  $next.addClass('active')
  this.sliding = false
  this.$element.trigger('slid')
}
```

Kind of strange they didn't mention it, though.

Comment: THANK YOU! That saved me a headache!